# Is the Mosin a 1 or 2 shot kill?

Tags: dayz-standalone

On the DayZ standalone wiki it says that it is a 2 shot kill unless you hit the head. Many players have said otherwise, stating that it is a 1 shot anywhere on your opponent. Does anyone know the actual damage count for this weapon? I've always been able to take out people with 1 shot (sometimes not in the head) but I'm not sure if it was just due to them having low blood...

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but in my personal experience it seems ALL guns are one shot kills, except the FNX. Depending on where you hit them may also play some part in it.

Comment: have you ever tried the Sporter 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you shot upper body, then player will die or fall unconscious. If you shot lower body, then player will be alive and, maybe, fall on the ground, if you shot in the leg.

From my expirience, this weapon also depend on Murphy's law. You will kill with one shot on long distance, but in close combat you'll need 2 shots and reloading time will be enough to your enemy to land you deadly shot or critical hits with axe.